# Customizing linux kernel for new board

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

I'm porting/customizing linux kernel for our board. I will base on atmel evolution board configuration, and I need to overwrite some startup routines and add our drivers.

Is there any document, link, forum where I can get information how to make it in Linux way ?
Which files can I overwrite, and which shall I create from scratch ? 
Is this a Board Support Package question ?

Thank you

Comment: There are many resources (even books) about the Linux kernel internals. What did you read?

Comment: Thank you for "Linux kernel internals" hint, I think it's what I'm looking for. .... Answer: Embedded Linux Primer, Linux Device Drivers and lot of online guides about device drivers development. I also ported linux to our old board, but i'm afraid that it was "ugly style". I simply look for something like tutorial about porting linux.

Comment: good question, Im looking for that too since mouths and found nothing, did u find something useful , any help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there is short and simple answer to your question. To accomplish this task you should more or less good understand Linux as distribution (kernel + boot scripts + user space software) work together and how make them be a friends.

I could recommend you book, which I found extremely useful as embedded Linux engineer:  [Embedded Linux Primer: A Practical Real-World Approach (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137017839) I am quite confident it will answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's it. Short, nice, fresh:

http://free-electrons.com/blog/elce-2012-slides-porting-linux-to-new-arm-soc/

Comment: good overview but not very specific. Might also be outdated if you're trying to do something with lk 3.10+